# Do you use "going to present" or "will present"? -The Future

Tags: grammar, future

I'm currently preparing a speech for a debate for my school subject "Global Studies" and during that speech I have to explain our teamline so I thought about starting with "I'm going to start with..", then go on with "Our next speaker is going to continue with.." and so on.
Well, now I was wondering if it's possible to use the "will-future" too or should I only use the "going to future" in that case?
I'm not sure if it's okay to use the "will-future" since the "going to future" is used if you have planned something and since we have planned out our teamline I thought it's only possible to use the going to future.

Am I right with that?

Comment: It's possible to use either. This planned/unplanned rule taught in ESL courses only approximates the way that these two futures are used in English.

Answer (score 1):

While both can be used successfully the 'will-future' is more forceful.  Remember that the debate includes your speech. It should reiterate your team's position as well as introduce the team and their topics. As your team's introductory speaker you have the first opportunity to say 'this is what we **will** do'.

Comment: Agreed. *Going to* does imply planning, but that's already clear from context (describing the plan for the speech). *Will* describes a certainty, which I would take in this context as strong confidence in the plan.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either: the future can be expressed using 'will x', 'shall x', 'am about to x', 'am going to x' etc. interchangeably.